# Access 2016: The method you tried to invoke on an object failed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

This is on an upgraded Access solution from 2015 to 2016.  Also, new solution is using a MySQL backend database on Amazon Web Server.  So I'm not sure which change may be causing the issue.

When I execute the code

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

Or, when I just move to another record, causing an intrinsic save, I get the error 2759 with the following description:

> The method you tried to invoke on an object failed

Also in some conditions when I apply a filter to the form I get this error also.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to fix this, and/or what is causing it?

Comment: Share you code. It may be that, you are getting error because of some other code. Also share screenshot of the error. This will help users at SO to suggest solution to the problem.